# Does each vagrant reload remove changes?

Tags: vagrant

Say you `vagrant up`, then `vagrant ssh`, then you start doing stuff like `sudo apt-get install composer` and you get composer installed in your Unix vagrant. If you do a `vagrant reload` is it going to reinitialize everything you did and remove them? So when it's reloaded you'll have to re-run `sudo apt-get install composer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `vagrant reload` does not modify the state of the VM. it only restarts it and loads the new Vagrantfile config.